# How I use where clause with computed column to get related records only

Tags: sql, firebird

I read this FAQ http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq289/ and I want to use select to count detail record from current record so I tried this

```
((
select count(*) from detail_table where detail_table.id = id
))
```

But I did not get correct values I got numbers like 19 where in fact it is the total number of records in `detail_table`! How can I get only the count of records related to current master record in master table?

Comment: What is `id` ? PK of detail_table or FK to master table?

Comment: `id` is FK to master table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `id` refers to the `id` column of `detail_table` and not of the master table. So it is the equivalent of:

```sql
select count(*) from detail_table where detail_table.id = detail_table.id
```

Which means you are simply counting all rows. Instead - assuming the master table is `master_table` - you should use:

```sql
select count(*) from detail_table where detail_table.id = master_table.id
```

Note that, as also mentioned in the FAQ you link to, you should really consider using a view instead of a computed column when referencing other tables as it is not very good for performance.

The view equivalent would be something like

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW master_with_detail_count
AS
SELECT master_table.id, coalesce(c.detail_count, 0) as detail_count
FROM master_table
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, count(*) as detail_count FROM detail GROUP BY id) c
    ON c.id = master.id
```

Comment: Thanks, if possible please post how the view should look like, just for this field.

Comment: I need to list all records from master table whether is has records from detail table or not.